# method returning more length then the properties

Tags: javascript, methods

i have a code snippet  below but i dont know why the condition is not true??

```
Object.prototype.keys = function(){ 
  var keys = []; 
  for ( var i in this ) 
    keys.push( i ); 
  return keys; 
}; 

var obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }; 

log( obj.keys().length == 3, "We should only have 3 properties." );
```

obj have only three properties but the returning me flase while i have also write the this statment before return

```
log(keys)
//outpue a,b,c
```

but i dont know why it is flase and the length is 4?

Comment: Why do you override the native Object.keys function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For insure that your object has direct property only but not inherited then you can use `hasOwnproperty()` something like this.

```
 for ( var i in this ) {
    if(this.hasOwnProperty(i)){
    //--use this--^ to insure that your object has direct property not inherited.    
        keys.push(i); 
    }
 }

 // returns  keys[a, b, c]
```

Comment: +1 yes working. so what was the fourth inherited property property?

Answer (score 3):

You are getting back the additional property "keys" which you set on the Object type.. which now all Objects have.

It would be the same as if you set the function on your object

```
var obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, keys: function(){ ... } };
```

4 Properties

Delegate the keys function to another class.. or just make it a function in your JS rather than a member function of your object.  Don't attach they keys function with Object.prototype.. since appending it to all objects makes it incorrect for all objects.